# Rails Filter Index With Checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I feel like I should preface this by saying that I know there are a few dozen questions on this topic already, but I've spent a few hours reading through them all at this point without finding an outline of a simple, straightforward way to do this. Why does this seem like such a difficult operation? Is there really not a streamlined way to do this?

I have an Employee model, which includes a string "location". In the index view, I want to filter allow the user to click check boxes to filter the displayed employees. I managed to put together *something*, but when I click the submit button it tries to use the show route, rather than redisplaying the index.

Here's the index...

```
index.html.erb

<% provide(:title, 'All employees') %>
<h1>All Employees</h1>

<!-- create check boxes for filterining -->
<%= form_tag url: employees_path, :method => :get do %>
    <%= label_tag "NYC" %>  <%= check_box_tag 'location[]', "NYC", checked: true %>
    <%= check_box_tag 'location[]', "Paris" %>
    <%= check_box_tag 'location[]', "Rome" %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
<% end %>


<table>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Location</th>
  </tr>
  <% @employees.each do |employee| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to employee.name, employee %></td>
    <td><%= employee.location %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

And the controller...

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    #@employees = Employee.all
    @employees = Employee.where("location IN (?)", params[:location])
  end

  def show
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Here's the log....

```
Started GET "/employees" for 64.134.36.1 at 2015-09-09 03:59:08 +0000
  [1m[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"[0m
Processing by EmployeesController#index as HTML
  [1m[35mEmployee Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT "employees".* FROM "employees" WHERE (location IN (NULL))
  Rendered employees/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 285ms (Views: 268.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)


Started POST "/employees?method=get&url=%2Femployees" for 64.134.36.1 at 2015-09-09 03:59:12 +0000
Processing by EmployeesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ewCa8gn7P5X8SstapIWMacMj2qqw4SLWw9lrCqLt0HHeiNKqvSftDvCEC7AJo9NdZh0N2hyzifZoPRDgXzkm5w==", "location"=>["NYC"], "commit"=>"Submit", "method"=>"get", "url"=>"/employees"}
  Rendered employees/create.html.erb within layouts/application (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 81ms (Views: 79.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Could you please post the `log` after submitting the form?

Comment: Is this really in quotes? "employees_url".  If so, the method should be unquoted.

Comment: Whoops, that was indeed in quotes. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Added the log generated after submitting the form. Looks like somehow it's passing NULL...?

Comment: @hobscrk777, You're submit action requested as a `POST`, not as `GET`. It's hitting you're `create` action not the `index`.

Answer (score 0):

Do a slide change on your `from_tag` as following, `ruby` code will not evaluate in `""`

```
 <%= form_tag url: employees_path, :method => :get do %>
  #your codes goes here
```

Or

```
 <%= form_tag employees_path, :method => :get do %>
  #your codes goes here
```

Or

```
 <%= form_tag '/employees', :method => :get do %>
  #your codes goes here
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it'll solve the problem,

```
<form action='<%= employees_path %>' method='get' >
  # other codes 
</form>
```

Comment: Is there a way to initially show all the employees, and then filter down using the check boxes? Right now the index starts off not displaying any employees, because the controller is telling the view to only display those with checked values found in the table, but on the initial view the user hasn't checked any boxes.

Comment: You can do this using a different controller action, with ajax rendering using `remote: true`